# Clients continuously get new ips from server 2012 DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

Clients continuously get new ips from server 2012 DHCP. I can release and renew and get a new ip every time. I am also not able to configure reservations for the same machines. I have considered the possibility of a DHCP consumption attack but not sure that's the case. My current settings are for 1 day addresses.  Any thoughts?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact configuration of the DHCP server? Is the client getting a new IP even if you just *renew* the address (`ipconfig /renew` on the client) *without first releasing* the current IP (from the question I get that you first release then renew)? I'd have a look at the lease times reported by `ipconfig /all` to see if you see any hints of something going wrong.

Comment: You can try specifying the static IP once the client is established and then add that address to an address-list? I was just thinking ... as an option.